# What's the difference between withOpacity() and withAlpha() methods

Tags: flutter

I want to know what's the main difference between the `withAlpha()` and `withOPacity()` methods  for the `Color` object, and when should I use each one in my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the flutter documentation found in the following links :

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color/withAlpha.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color/withOpacity.html

`withAlpha()` Returns a new color that matches this color with the alpha channel replaced with a (which ranges from 0 to 255).

`withOpacity()` Returns a new color that matches this color with the alpha channel replaced with the given opacity (which ranges from 0.0 to 1.0).

the deference is with how much range (levels) of this color (the color you are using) you can apply.